# How do i add multiple pages to my IOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I understand this may be a stupid question, but i can not find the answer. How do i add multiple pages to my IOS app? I know you can use page control, but what code would i use to enable it?

**Edit**
Sorry, i will try to be a little more clear. I am creating a soundboard app, and have more buttons than can fit on one page. I would like it so that the user can swipe the screen over to a new screen with more buttons.

Comment: Do you mean how do you change a view? Like from one screen to another?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you described, of wanting to swipe between screens, your best bet is to embed all the “pages” side-by-side in a `UIScrollView`, and set the scroll view's `pagingEnabled` property to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this sample code from Apple. Does exactly what you're looking for.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html